# Calculating cos(x) with a Taylor Series

Tags: java, trigonometry, taylor-series

Im Currently working on one of my excercises for university.
I have to calculate the cos(x) by using a taylor series. Im also just allowed to use Math.PI which is why i implemented my own pow, square and factorial methods. But im just getting an NaN as a result for -.5 while it should be 0.87

Below im putting the current state of my class.

```
    class Cosinus{

    private static double square(double x){ 
        return x*x;
    }


    public static double pow(double basis, int exp){ 
    if(exp == 0){
      return 1;
    }else{
      return (square(pow(basis,exp/2))*(exp%2==1?basis:1));
    }
    }

  public static int fac(int n){
    int result = 1;
    while (n > 1){
      result *= n;
      n -= 1;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    if(args.length != 1){
       System.out.println("ERROR PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER");
     }
    else if(Double.parseDouble(args[0])>((Math.PI)*2) || Double.parseDouble(args[0]) < ((Math.PI)*-2)){
       System.out.println("ERROR PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 2 PI   ");
     }
    else {
      double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
      if(x < 0) x *= -1;
      double sum = 1;
      for(int i=2; i<=20; i++){
        sum -= (pow(x, (i*4))/fac(i*4))-(pow(x, (i*4+2))/fac(i*4+2));
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me with this

Comment: For sure your `fac()` method is going to overflow.  You can't use `int` for huge numbers like that.

Comment: Already changed it to long thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Factorial(20) is 2e18 which is larger than an `int` can hold. If you change your `fac` method to use `long` instead it will give you the expected result:

```
public static long fac(int n) {
  long result = 1;
  while (n > 1) {
    result *= n;
    --n;
  }
  return result;
}
```